Laravel tests do not show the reason why the test does not pass
It used to be that when I wrote tests in Laravel, when running the tests, I would get information as to why a particular test was not passing, e.g. expected status was 200 and received status was 404, etc. Nowadays I only get information whether it passes or not. I run the tests using sail artisan test.

How can I change this?
@Edit
I tryed using phpunit, command:
./vendor/bin/phpunit inside artisan bash but it displays me this:
PHPUNIT

That is the new command, I really hate it because of that, just run sail ./vendor/bin/phpunit

The sail artisan test command is an alias for Pest, which is a minimalist testing library. By default, Pest displays less detail than PHPUnit.

I Updated my question

@KaneOgg88 do you have any dd()?

sure. I can debug and found problem via dd but it doesn't convenient solution

Run artisan commands (clear commands first) as www-data
USER www-data
RUN php artisan optimize:clear && 
php artisan icons:clear && 
php artisan icons:cache
Switch back to root for other tasks
USER root

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

What has this to do with the solution of showing output of the other command?
